# Can't access element of Array

Tags: arrays, angular, observable

I'm adding elements to an array using a service, which successfully adds the elements. I can see the data populated with a console.log

I can't however access the element.

```
this.routingService.getNode(startNode).subscribe(node => {
      node.forEach(node => {
        this.openSet.push(new MapNode(node.id, node.lon, node.lat, this.routingService.getNodeNeighbours(node.id)));
      });
    });

    console.log(this.openSet); // this prints out the below screenshot
```

[image]

However, when I use something like:

```
console.log(this.openSet[0]);
```

I get output of 'undefined'. I'm not sure if I'm being really thick right now in how I'm accessing it or not...

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post what you see when you do console.log(JSON.stringify(this.openSet));

Comment: please add the javascript tag to the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @baao how will this question be a duplicate of the one you mentioned. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Explained in the community wiki answer @Aravind

Comment: @baao you are right.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subscribe` works asynchron, so `console.log()` will log before the `forEach` loop runs. It's the same async behaviour as in this little piece of code

```js
let foo = [];

setTimeout(() => {
  foo.push(1);
  foo.push(2);
}, 500);

console.log(foo); // logs []
```

Please see the duplicate post for options on how to work with asynchronity.

[How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. printing out the array using JSON.stringify returned empty, so confirms your answer. Thank you! :)